# $\Bbb N$ with primes deleted

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

Consider the sequence https://oeis.org/A018252 which is $\Bbb N$ with the primes deleted. For example $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ would become $\{1,4\}.$ The difference between the elements would be $4-1=3.$

I'm interested in the differences between the remaining elements after the deletion of the primes, and its behavior. The first few differences are: $\{3,2,2,1,1,2,2,1\}.$

Specifically,

> Q1: For a sequence $S$ that keeps track of the difference between successive non-prime elements, what function can approximate it the best?
>
> Q2: How many primes are in $S$ below a given threshold?

Comment: $1$ is not composite (it's not prime, either; it's a unit). If $n$ is large, then the Prime Number Theorem (look it up!) says there are roughly $n/\log n$ primes up to $n$, so the space between any two primes in your reordering would be roughly $\log n$.

Comment: Without any additional requirements it's hard to say anything specific. For example, your version of $\mathbb{N}'_5$ certainly works, but it's only one of many options. Another option could be $\mathbb{N}'_5=(1,2,3,4,5)$ (yes, in the same order!) or $\mathbb{N}'_5=(2,3,4,5,1)$ because they both satisfy the given conditions.

Comment: Any reaction to the comments, Ultra?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I edited to include that primes must be at the beginning and end of the permuted set.

Comment: @Ultradark I don't think primes can have exactly equal spacing if you insist they are beginning and end

Comment: There are many unclear points here: e.g. for $n=6$, the primes won't be evenly spaced, and some composites will be adjacent, so how do you define the "spacing between composite elements"?  May I suggest: can you show, in addition to the $n=5$ example, also examples for $n=6, n=10$: how would you re-order in each case and what you would consider as the "spacing between composite elements"?  With more examples, we'd have a better chance of _guessing_ what you mean.  :)

Comment: I rewrote the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop first $3$ as that one is not necessary and is generally wrong. The rest of the series is $2$ in case we have a twin prime and $1$ in case we do not.

The series cannot contain any other number except $2$ and $1$. So we are interested in the distribution of $2$'s but this is equivalent to asking the questions about the distribution of twin primes. This is only conjectured at the moment as we do not even know if there are infinite number of them.

It is conjectured that the number of twin primes up to x is

$$\pi_2(x) \sim \frac{x}{(\ln x)^2} $$

Comment: Correction:  2's happen every time there's a prime (because $(p+1) - (p-1) = 2$), not every time there's a twin prime.